# Twitter oauth emoji issue - encoding?

Tags: php, twitter, utf-8, oauth, emoji

I am using twitter oauth to get a user's timeline. We are saving this to our database.

When posts containing emojis come down, we are getting the emoji like: `ðŸ˜˜` rather than in the desired `\ue415` format.

The format we are getting them in is not useful to us as we are piping them out to an app which is unable to work with the former but is fine with the latter.

I would assume this is an issue with encoding, is there anyway we can get the emojis in the latter format?

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);
foreach ($tweets as $key => $tweet) {
    echo $tweet->text;
}
```

Comment: Can you try sending a UTF-8 header? `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`... this looks like an issue with your browser not getting the correct encoding.